# Rails work around for nesting forms

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms) on SO. form elements may not be nested.
What I did was have a form for a model that had images, I in turn then nested the images in form tags so that they can easily be deleted seperately from their "parent" model using the jQuery Ajax form plugin. The problem as I found out is that you cannot do this, so I am looking for an easy workaround that lets me use the form helper or something similar (so that I get the anti-csrf tag etc. etc) and can delete with ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the old `accepts_nested_attributes` + `fields_for :child_item` pairing, allows you to have a parent object with many child items in their own little forms within the main form.

- [Read more about nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)
- [A handy railscast to follow for multiple child instances, with javascript controls](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised)